# Where is this inequality coming from?

Tags: inequality

It's probably simple but I'm not sure why I'm not seeing it. The inequality is from a paper:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i (x_i-1)(1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j) &\leq\begin{split}
&\mathbin{\hphantom{+}}x_1(2\rho_1 + \rho_2\alpha_{21}+ \rho_3\alpha_{31}+\rho_4\alpha_{41}) \\&+x_2(\rho_1\alpha_{12} + 2\rho_2+ \rho_3\alpha_{32}+\rho_4\alpha_{42}) \\&+ x_3(\rho_1\alpha_{13} + \rho_2\alpha_{23}+ 2\rho_3+\rho_4\alpha_{43}) \\&+ x_4(\rho_1\alpha_{14} + \rho_2\alpha_{24} + 2\rho_3\alpha_{34}+2\rho_4)
\end{split}
\end{align*}$$

Hopefully I copied that from the paper correctly. They say this is due to the positivity of  $x_i(t)$. I know $\rho_i > 0$, and though it's not stated, I believe each $\alpha$ should be positive as well. I'm not understanding why all these twos are appearing and what they did to get at this inequality.

Adding a thought:

Since $x_i$ is positive, it should be that $x_i -1 < x_i$ and $1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j \leq 1$ (if the $\alpha_{ij} > 0$) , so shouldn't we have $\sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i (x_i-1)(1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j) < \sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i x_i$? It seems like that's wrong since the paper bounds by something bigger, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: It is page 15: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/267192419_Multiplicative-noise_can_suppress_chaotic_oscillation_in_Lotka-Volterra_type_competitive_model

Comment: So the paper is "Multiplicative-noise can suppress chaotic oscillation in Lotka-Volterra type competitive model" by P.S. Mandal and Malay Banerjee, *Mathematical Modelling of Natural Phenomena* vol. 7(6), Jan. 2012.  You have specialized the equation by taking all $\sigma_i = 0$.

Comment: Well the $\sigma_i$ is a separate part of the inequality, which has no relationship to the first part I'm confused by